# How to use DataTables Bootstrap Styling with Browserify?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatables, browserify, browserify-shim

I'm trying to use the [DataTables Bootstrap styling](https://www.datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html) stitched together by **Browserify** but when I access a page using the resultant Browserify bundle the JS Console displays an "Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'datatables'.

My `require('datatables');` statement works just fine and loads DataTables successfully, but when I attempt to `require('datatables-bootstrap');` the page does not load.  Browserify does successfully compile the bundle.

I acquire the DataTables files via `bower install --save datatables` but jQuery though `npm install --save jquery`.  [Here are the DataTables source files](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/tree/master/media/js)

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
  "bootstrap": "^3.3.4",
  "jquery": "^1.11.2"
},
"browser": {
  "datatables": "./bower_components/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js",
  "datatables-bootstrap": "./bower_components/datatables/media/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"
},
"browserify": {
  "transform": [
    "browserify-shim"
  ]
},
"browserify-shim": {
  "datatables": {
    "exports": "datatables",
    "depends": [
      "jquery:$"
    ]
  },
  "datatables-bootstrap": {
    "exports": null,
    "depends": [
      "jquery:$",
      "datatables"
    ]
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```
'use strict';
var $ = global.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('datatables');
require('datatables-bootstrap'); // <-- causes the error
```

Comment: I'm guessing you solved this but was looking into it out of interest. I just made a repo at https://github.com/YPCrumble/datatables-SO and couldn't reproduce the error.